# Does Panda support different column specs within same fixed length file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am just looking at the Pandas library with a view to seeing whether or not it is suitable for a task I have.

I have a fixed width file. Which I have defined like this

```
col_names = ['RecType','Region','SecCode','Data','FRF','Date']
col_def =[
    [0,1],[1,4],[4,5],[5,123],[123,128],[128,132]
]
```

and am reading like this:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(datafile, colspecs=col_def, names=col_names)
```

The pattern above is true for every line in the file. However, the structure of the data referenced by the column 'Data' changes depending on the value of 'SecCode'

For example if SecCode had a value of 'P' the data would need to be split up as follows:

```
col_names = ['RecType','Region','SecCode','SubCode','Name', 'Data','FRF','Date']
col_def =[
    [0,1],[1,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,16],[16,122],[122,127],[127,131]
]
```

But if the value of SecCode was 'W' then the data needs to be split like this:

```
col_names = ['RecType','Region','SecCode','Name','SubCode', 'Data','FRF','Date']
col_def =[
    [0,1],[1,4],[4,5],[5,15],[15,16],[16,122],[122,127],[127,131]
]
```

Example Data

```
SAFRPAWIDGETA-1    DAAEDAFD26   D      02172DMEDAPC1E S     TF BJA DA      08120071        D   + 02297   -300          S  378651811
SAFRWWIDGETB-1 X   DAAEDAFD26   D      02172DMEDAPC2P                                                                     378661811
SAFRPAWIDGETA-2    DAAEDAFD26   D      03152DMEDAPC1E S     TF BJA DA      08120051        D   + 01657   -300          S  378671811
SAFRWWIDGETB-2 X   DAAEDAFD26   D      03152DMEDAPC2P                                                                     378681811
SAFRWWIDGETB-3 X   DAAEDAFD26   D      041MD26 DAPC1EY M    TF BJA DA      08120041        D     01329   -300          S  378691811
SAFRPAWIDGETA-3    DAAEDAFD26   D      041MD26 DAPC2P                                                                     378701811
SAFRPAWIDGETA-4    DAAEDAFD26   D      042BJA  DAD 1V M     TF       2610        + 00420     06600                     A  378711811
SAFRWWIDGETB-4 X   DAAEDAFD26   D      042BJA  DAD 2P                                                                     378721811
SAFRPAWIDGETA-5    DAAEDAFD26   D      052BJA  DAD 1VE      FM BJA DA      359200103230    D   + 06200    160        - A  378731811
SAFRWWIDGETB-5 X   DAAEDAFD26   D      052BJA  DAD 2P                                                                     378741811
```

In this example data the two SubCodes are A when SecCode ='P' and X when SecCode = 'W'

Is this possible and, if yes, how would I go about it?

Comment: I don't think that there's an automatic method but I presume you could iterate over the lines in the file, lookup `line[4:5]` and then decide how to read the individual line into a temporary DataFrame, which is then appended to the actual `df`; could you perhaps give a few lines of your text file so that we have something to play with?

Comment: @Asmus I've added some example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest iterating over the file's lines, deciding whether it's type "P" or "W", and then using a specific `col_def` (see comments in code).

**Note:** I did not find a way to have `pd.read_fwf()` import a single line into a DataFrame, while using `col_names`; it is since always putting the line values into the column headers when reading in a line. Consequently, I'm using the weird looking construct of `read_fwf(…).columns.values` to get the values. Alternatively, you could also use `vals= [ line.rstrip()[a:b] for (a,b) in col_def_P ]` to directly get the values as a list.

```py
import pandas as pd

## create an empty DataFrame with column headers:
col_names=['RecType','Region','SecCode','SubCode', 'Name', 'Value','FRF','Date']
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
## create the column definitions for .read_fwf()
col_def_P=[[0,1],[1,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,16],[16,122],[122,127],[127,131]]
## note that for type "W", we use a "non-continuous" order, i.e. we read [15,16] first,
#  and [5,14] next; this way, we have the values in the anticipated ordering
col_def_W=[[0,1],[1,4],[4,5],[15,16],[5,15],[16,122],[122,127],[127,131]]

with open('untitled.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if(line[4:5]=="P"):
            vals=( pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(line),colspecs=col_def_P).columns.values )
            ## or:
            # vals= [ line.rstrip()[a:b] for (a,b) in col_def_P ]
            df.loc[len(df)]=vals
        elif(line[4:5]=="W"):
            vals=( pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(line),colspecs=col_def_W).columns.values )
            df.loc[len(df)]=vals

print(df)
```

yields:

```
  RecType Region SecCode SubCode        Name                                    Value    FRF  Date
0       S    AFR       P       A  WIDGETA-1      DAAEDAFD26   D      02172DMEDAPC1...  37865  1811
1       S    AFR       W       X  WIDGETB-1      DAAEDAFD26   D      02172DMEDAPC2...  37866  1811
2       S    AFR       P       A  WIDGETA-2      DAAEDAFD26   D      03152DMEDAPC1...  37867  1811
3       S    AFR       W       X  WIDGETB-2      DAAEDAFD26   D      03152DMEDAPC2...  37868  1811
4       S    AFR       W       X  WIDGETB-3      DAAEDAFD26   D      041MD26 DAPC1...  37869  1811
5       S    AFR       P       A  WIDGETA-3      DAAEDAFD26   D      041MD26 DAPC2...  37870  1811
6       S    AFR       P       A  WIDGETA-4      DAAEDAFD26   D      042BJA  DAD 1...  37871  1811
7       S    AFR       W       X  WIDGETB-4      DAAEDAFD26   D      042BJA  DAD 2...  37872  1811
8       S    AFR       P       A  WIDGETA-5      DAAEDAFD26   D      052BJA  DAD 1...  37873  1811
9       S    AFR       W       X  WIDGETB-5      DAAEDAFD26   D      052BJA  DAD 2...  37874  1811
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show me how to do that.
Yes, it does work but it is too slow for my needs, the file is 500,000 lines and the Pandas approach takes 5+ minutes. In the end it proved quicker to parse the file into individual files for each SecCode type - 50 secs

Comment: @TheWelshDragon Interesting, did not expect `pandas` to be *that much* slower. Did you by any chance also test the speed of the `vals= [ line.rstrip()[a:b] for (a,b) in col_def_P ]`-approach?

Comment: Just tried it. I stopped it once 5 minutes had elapsed. It may be quicker but it is still significantly slower than using .readlines() and regex parsing.

Comment: @TheWelshDragon I guess that *does make sense*, thanks for testing anyway!